# Python script to remove all data from values in a the Json file

Tags: python, json, windows

Been searching the forums for this query, and seems fairly straightforward how would I remove all the data from values in JSON file to NULL or "", using python?

Example of JSON Before:

```
{
     “StringProperty”: “StringValue”,
    “NumberProperty”: 10,
    “FloatProperty”: 20.13,
    “BooleanProperty”: true,
    “EmptyProperty”: null
}
```

Example of JSON after python script run.

```
{
     “StringProperty”:
    “NumberProperty”:
    “FloatProperty”: 
    “BooleanProperty”: 
    “EmptyProperty”:
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
def del_none(N):
    """
    Delete keys with the value ``None`` in a dictionary, recursively.

    """
    # For Python 3, write `list(d.items())`; `N.items()` won’t work
    for key, value in list(N.items()):
        if value is None:
            del N[key]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            del_none(value)
    return N  # For convenience
```

But this isn't quite what I want, though.

Any assistance with writing this python script is welcome; no idea where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: [read the python documentation for the json module it has loads of examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: Sure thing updated the initial query

Answer (score 0):

To remove the json values you could update the recursive function you already have there.

Maybe there is some existing optimized function though...

```
import json

s = '{"StringProperty": "StringValue", ' \
    '"NumberProperty": 10, ' \
    '"FloatProperty": 20.13, ' \
    '"BooleanProperty": true, ' \
    '"EmptyProperty": null,' \
    '"NestedProperty": {' \
        '"NestedStringProperty": "StringValue", ' \
        '"NestedNumberProperty": 10}' \
    '}'
# first convert it to dict
dct = json.loads(s)

def clear_dict_values(d: dict) -> dict:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d[key] = clear_dict_values(value)
        else:
            d[key] = None  # or ""
    return d

print(clear_dict_values(dct))
```

Produces:

```
{'StringProperty': None, 'NumberProperty': None, 'FloatProperty': None, 'BooleanProperty': None, 'EmptyProperty': None, 'NestedProperty': {'NestedStringProperty': None, 'NestedNumberProperty': None}}
```

---

If you are sure it will never be nested, you can go for oneliner `dct = {k: None for k in dct.keys()}`